# SQL DELETE Query help..joining the same table together

Tags: sql, join

I have a database that I need to write a delete query for.

There are thousands of participants in the database, and the table includes their internal id (first column) and then employment statuses. The table is called `EE_EMPL_CAT` The category ID is `CAT_ID`, and `STAT_CD` is the status of that category (employment category):

[image: table example for 1 participant[][1]]

Now I need to make a delete query to delete the rows that include `CAT_ID=4433 & STAT_CD ='NO'`. But I only need these deleted if that same participant (=`prsn_intn_id`) also has `CAT_ID=430 AND STAT_CD='AFACTF'`. Also, to make sure all of these are current, I included an infinite end date (`EFENDDT='2299-12-31'`).

My attempt at the code:

```
#UPDATE
#AQUA-435
#TOLERANCE-435

DELETE FROM &DATABASE..EE_EMPL_CAT     A,
           & DATABASE..EE_EMPL_CAT     B
WHERE A.PRSN_INTN_ID = B.PRSN_INTN_ID
  AND A.EMPL_CAT_ID = 430
  AND A.EE_EMPLCAT_EFENDDT = '2299-12-31'
  AND A.EMPL_STAT_CD = 'AFACTF'
  AND B.EMPL_CAT_ID = 4433
  AND B.EE_EMPLCAT_EFENDDT = '2299-12-31'
  AND B.EMPL_STAT_CD = 'NO'
```

Comment: Both images look the same. Also, don't post image. post textual content.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the edits I have made to improve the quality of the question (click on the edit link above my pic to see the changes). Note how code is indented with 4 spaces, code appearing in phrases is marked with backticks. I have also embedded the image for you, as you do not have the reputation yet to do that yourself. Good luck!

Comment: awesome, tricot.. i truly appreciate it. the changes make my post look much more organized. now hopefully it can get solved!! thanks!!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.